# Python/Django environment on Windows 7

Tags: python, mysql, django, apache, xampp

Can someone tell me real quick how you set up a Django environment on Windows? I need Apache, MYSQL, SQLite and Python. I have a XAMPP and WAMP server on my computer that I use for PHP web applications. I just need someone to tell me how **you** personally set up a DJango environment on your windows machines. I am quite new to the Python world, so please excuse my ignorance. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Do you *really* need Apache? You don't need it for development, as you should use the built-in development server. And why both MySQL and sqlite?

Comment: I guess I don't **need** Apache. I am happy to hear that Django has an internal server. I want both MYSQL and SQLite because I want experiment them using Python. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python has some installation tools which make installing packages a breeze.

First install python. There are executables for different versions available.
http://www.python.org/getit/releases/2.7.3/

Then install python setup tools: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/

After this you can install `pip`:

`easy_install pip`

Once pip is installed you can install django by using `pip install django`. If these commands are not in your path you will have to execute them from your python directory!

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rIVwVOpwpsA

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate the video too.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need apache or mysql on you dev machine, django has a http server for testing and uses sqlite for default.

after setting up your project just use:

python manage.py runserver

then you should be able to open your django project on your browser: `http://localhost:8000/`

I also suggest that you take a look on [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.org)

Answer (score 1):

I use [cygwin](http://cygwin.org) with the python, vim, and rxvt-native packages installed.

This gives me a Linux like environment on my Windows machine without actually having to have Linux installed.

Comment: You definitely should. If you have any further questions just let me know in comments and I'll answer!

Comment: Thank you so much Nick, I really appreciate it!